# Changing MySQL Data Directory on EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance set up and I'm trying to move the MySQL data directory to mounted storage.

The default data directory is:

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/data
```

I've copied that directory entirely to

```
/mnt/mysql_data
```

Then I changed the path in my.cnf to the following:

```
datadir=/mnt/mysql_data
```

and renamed the old directory to be sure I'm using the new one.

I've given proper permissions to MySQL on the new directory - but I don't even think MySQL is trying to get there.  When I try to restart mysql I get errors about the previous data directory:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql
111122 18:50:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
touch: cannot touch `/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log': No such file or directory
111122 18:50:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: 739: cannot create /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log: Directory nonexistent
eval: 1: cannot create /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log: Directory nonexistent
111122 18:50:50 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/ip-10-120-253-190.pid ended
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: 783: cannot create /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log: Directory nonexistent
```

Am I missing a configuration step somewhere?  I've seen others with issues solve it by adjusting apparmor, but I don't even have the file "/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld" that they're supposed to be changing.  Plus, my problem doesn't seem to be that mysql can't access the new directory - it's that it's still using the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Amazon's control script "/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh" is executing a mysql config script at /opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh

Annoyingly, this script overrides a few key settings from the my.cnf file.  Updating them there fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure mysql to use the new log directory, please edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf (in this case I'm using Debian) and update

```
general_log_file = /mnt/data/log
```

Good luck.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file  That looks like the name of the log file to me, not the path?  My my.cnf does not have a setting for general_log_file so I would assume it should be attempting to write to the data directory.